# How to set Java File Encoding and Java Default Locale in Linux CentOS server?

Tags: java, linux, centos, locale

Could you guide me on how to set "Java File Encoding" and "Java Default Locale" in Linux CentOS server ? I would like to set the following.

Java File Encoding Cp1253
Java Default Locale el_GR

I had tried setting in bashrc, but its not working. Please advise.

I have full access to my Linux machine and installed Java via yum.

Comment: Do you want to change it only to JVM or to the whole system?

Comment: @marcospereira .. Thank you! I want to change only for the JVM..

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass it to JVM via command line arguments:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=CP1253 -Duser.language=el -Duser.country=GR YourClass
```

You can also add these to `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` which gets picked up by the JVM durring startup:

**Linux**:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=CP1253 -Duser.language=el -Duser.country=GR"
```

**Windows**:

```
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="..."
```

after which you can simply call

```
java YourClass
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The command for CentOS just works fine. Im using coldfusion on server, but its not taking the values which I mentioned. Refer the following output.        
`JVM Details
Java Version 1.6.0_04  
Java Vendor Sun Microsystems Inc.  
Java Vendor URL http://java.sun.com/  
Java Home /opt/jrun4/jre  
Java File Encoding UTF8  
Java Default Locale en_US`  .. Any idea?

Comment: thanks for your inputs and I just need to enter it in the right location of my application.

Comment: at risk of sounding cheeky, but if the answer contributed to your solution and answers the question where you didn't specify the fact that you are running in a servlet container,  an UP vote would be nice.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to see that coldfusion fetch the values from some other location and not from console or enviornment vairables which we set. I had added the following to "jvm.config" file of coldfusion and restarted it. Now everything looks great as expected.

-Dfile.encoding=CP1253 -Duser.language=el -Duser.country=GR